# Add key to mongoose model mongoDB with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model

I have the following model:

```
 const portfolioSchema = new Schema({
  profile: {
    fname: Schema.Types.Mixed,
    lname: Schema.Types.Mixed,
  }
  language: { type: String, required: true, default: 'fr' },
});
```

The objective of this schema is to have dynamic key for language like EN, IT, FR, etc .. I would like things to look like this:

```
 profile: {
    fname: {
       en: 'TOWTOW',
       it: 'TOTO',
    },
    lname: {
       en: 'BLABLA',
       it: 'BLABLA',
    },
    etc...
  }
```

What I do to insert a new language (for example FR) is the following thing:

```
const newLanguage: 'fr';

Portfolio.findById({ _id: portfolioId })
.exec().then((portfolioDB) => {

  portfolioDB.profile.fname[newLanguage] = portfolioDB.profile.fname[portfolioDB.language];
  portfolioDB.profile.lname[newLanguage] = portfolioDB.profile.lname[portfolioDB.language];

  portfolioDB.save((err, updatedPortfolio) => {
   if (err) {
     return res.send({ success: false });
   }

   console.log('updatedPortfolio', updatedPortfolio.profile);

   return res.send({ success: true, updatedPortfolio });
 })
```

The log of updatedPortfolio is correct, I properly see the new language key inserted. But unfortunately the database is not updated.

Does anyone have met this problem before ? Maybe the problem is because I am using Mixed schema ? Maybe I forget something during the request ? The weird thing is that updatedPortfolio has the good values, but not the database ..

Thank you for yout help.